# Como mudar a tipagem em Haskell

Tags: haskell

Quero que a função sorteie um número e, se este for maior que 7, mande uma mensagem de aprovação e chame essa função adicionar. Entretanto, minha função só cai no 'else'. Aparecendo a mensagem "reprovado". Acredito que seja a tipagem de IO Float com Float. Como resolver?

```
sortear :: Float -> Int
sortear x = ceiling(10 * x)


numeroSorteado :: IO ()
numeroSorteado = do    
    num <- randomIO :: IO Float
    print $ sortear num
    if(num >= 7) then
        do
            putStrLn ("Aprovado!" ++ "\n") >> adicionar
        else
        do
            putStrLn "Reprovado!"

adicionar = do
    putStrLn "Nome:"
    nome <- getLine
    putStrLn "Sobrenome:"
    sobrenome <- getLine
    putStrLn "CPF:"
    cpf <- getLine
    putStrLn "Idade:"
    idade <- getLine
    putStrLn "Salario:"
    salario <- getLine
    putStrLn "Cargo (Estagiario, Analista, Gerente, Diretor, VicePresidente ou Presidente) :"
    cargo <- getLine
    let new =  (nome ++ " "++ sobrenome ++ " " ++ cpf ++ " " ++ idade ++ " " ++ salario ++ " " ++ cargo ++ "\n")
    appendFile "funcionarios.txt" new
    putStrLn "Funcionario Salvo!"
```

Comment: A função ``adicionar`` não parece ser importante para reproduzirmos seu problem. É recomendável que você só coloque o código daquilo que interessa, e apague o restante para evitar distrações. Isso se chama exemplo mínimo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema no seu código deve-se à linha que contém a seguinte informação:

> num <- randomIO :: IO Float

Este **num** nunca será maior que 1, visto que `randomIO :: IO Float` gerá unicamente números de virgula flutuante que sejam menores que 1.

Uma solução para este problema passará pela implementação da função **randomRIO** de tipo `randomRIO :: Random a => (a, a) -> IO a` que gerá um número, limitado a um certo intervalo.

Uma possível resolução:

```
numeroSorteado :: IO ()
numeroSorteado = do    
       num <- randomRIO (1::Float,20::Float)
       print $ sortear num
       if(num >= 7) then
           do
               putStrLn ("Aprovado!" ++ "\n") >> adicionar
           else
           do
               putStrLn "Reprovado!"
```